# grails - RestClientBuilder

Tags: rest, grails, curl

I am using the current version of rest client builder plugin. I tested out the uri via curl:

```
curl --user username:password https://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/plan.json?os_authType=basic
```

I get the expected json in return. When I try to translate this to grails using the plugin like this:

```
RestBuilder rb = new RestBuilder()
    def response = rb.get("https://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/plan.json?os_authType=basic"){     
            auth 'username', 'password'
        }

response.json instanceof JSONObject
```

I get this error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Why does it work in curl and not with the plugin? How do I get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: who about Http instead of https ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the root certificate to the store of the trusted ones.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html

---

## Import the Certificate as a Trusted Certificate

Before you can grant the signed code permission to read a specified file, you need to import Susan's certificate as a trusted certificate in your keystore.

Suppose that you have received from Susan

- the signed JAR file `sCount.jar`, which contains the `Count.class` file, and
- the file `Example.cer`, which contains the public key certificate for the public key corresponding to the private key used to sign the JAR file.

Even though you created these files and they haven't actually been transported anywhere, you can simulate being someone other than the creater and sender, Susan. Pretend that you are now Ray. Acting as Ray, you will create a keystore named `exampleraystore` and will use it to import the certificate into an entry with an alias of `susan`.

A keystore is created whenever you use a `keytool` command specifying a keystore that doesn't yet exist. Thus we can create the `exampleraystore` and import the certificate via a single `keytool` command. Do the following in your command window.

1. Go to the directory containing the public key certificate file `Example.cer`. (You should actually already be there, since this lesson assumes that you stay in a single directory throughout.)
2. Type the following command on one line:

   **keytool -import -alias susan
      -file Example.cer -keystore exampleraystore**

Since the keystore doesn't yet exist, it will be created, and you will be prompted for a keystore password; type whatever password you want.

The `keytool` command will print out the certificate information and ask you to verify it, for example, by comparing the displayed certificate fingerprints with those obtained from another (trusted) source of information. (Each fingerprint is a relatively short number that uniquely and reliably identifies the certificate.) For example, in the real world you might call up Susan and ask her what the fingerprints should be. She can get the fingerprints of the `Example.cer` file she created by executing the command

**keytool -printcert -file Example.cer**

If the fingerprints she sees are the same as the ones reported to you by `keytool`, the certificate has not been modified in transit. In that case you let `keytool` proceed with placing a trusted certificate entry in the keystore. The entry contains the public key certificate data from the file `Example.cer` and is assigned the alias `susan`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable SSL check for RestBuilder.

See an example of code:

```
static Scheme disableSSLCheck() {

        def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        sslContext.init(null, [new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}

            @Override
            X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0]
            }
        }] as TrustManager[], new SecureRandom())
        def sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
        def httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", sf, 443)
        httpsScheme

    }
```

And register this Scheme to the RestClient:

```
Scheme httpsScheme = disableSSLCheck()
restClient.client.connectionManager.schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mb too late but have a look here.
https://gist.github.com/thomastaylor312/80fcb016020e4115aa64320b98fb0017

I do have it as separate method in my Integration test

```
 def static disableSSLCheck() {
    def nullTrustManager = [
            checkClientTrusted: { chain, authType -> },
            checkServerTrusted: { chain, authType -> },
            getAcceptedIssuers: { null }
    ]

    def nullHostnameVerifier = [
            verify: { hostname, session -> true }
    ]

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
    sc.init(null, [nullTrustManager as X509TrustManager] as TrustManager[], null)
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(nullHostnameVerifier as HostnameVerifier)
}
```

And then just

```
void "test authentication"(){
    given:
    String url = "j_spring_security_check"
    MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
    form.add("grant_type", "password")
    form.add("j_username", "vadim@ondeviceresearch.com")
    form.add("j_password", "notSecure")
    form.add("_spring_security_remember_me", "true")
    //TODO SET username and pass
    //todo get token back
    disableSSLCheck()
    when:
    RestResponse response = rest.post(host + url){
        accept("application/json")
        contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        body(form)
    }
    response
    then:
    response.status == 200
}
```